# Is $f$ differentiable at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a function  on $\mathbb{C}$ as follow

$$f(z)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{\mathrm{Im}(z^2)}{z|z|} & \text{if}\quad  z\neq 0\\ 0& \text{if} \quad z=0.\end{cases}$$

Is $f$ differentiable at $z=0$?

My approach:
$$\lim\limits_{z\to 0}\dfrac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}=\lim\limits_{z\to 0}\dfrac{\mathrm{Im}z^2}{z|z|} =0.$$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+%28Im+z%5E2%29%2F%28z%7Cz%7C%29+as+z+to+0

On the other hand, let $z=x+iy$ then $$f(z)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{2xy(x-iy)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} & \text{if}\quad  z\neq 0\\ 0& \text{if} \quad z=0.\end{cases}$$
We have $\lim\limits_{z\to 0}\dfrac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}=\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{2xy(x-iy)}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2}^3}$ doesn't exist.

I think Wolfram Alpha is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take $z = ih$ and make $h$ go to $0$

Comment: Is it $|z|$ or $z|z|$ in the denominator of $f$? And then also, which is it in the denominator of your derivative limit? They can't both be $z|z|$. I suspect that $f$ has $|z|$ in the denominator, and $z|z|$ is in the denominator of the derivative limit, as was originally written.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is negative from simpler observations. Along the diagonal $z=t(1+i)$, you have $$f(z)=\sqrt{2}\left| t\right|$$

EDIT

The statement of the question has changed. Now along the diagonal $z=t(1+i)$, you have $$f(z)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1+i}\frac{\left|t\right|}{t}$$ It is still clearly not differentiable, but now the reason is because it is not continuous.

Answer (score 0):

No, no, WolframAlpha assumed your $z$ to be real. Indeed, the limit does not exist.